# In PHPWord, Right and Left Align Words

Tags: php, phpword

I was wondering if there was anyway to left and right align some text on the same line. So for example a resume would have a company name aligned to the left, and a date aligned to the right, on the same line.

I was trying to do this with a text run, but doesn't seem to work. I know I can use `\t\t` but the left text is going to be different lengths, so the tabs will be very inconsistent.

This is just a simple example:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$textrun = $section->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText("Left Text", array(), array("align" => "left"));
$textrun->addText("Right Text", array(), array("align" => "right"));
```

Comment: How would you set alignment for individual words in MS Word itself? As far as I'm aware, you can only set alignment on paragraphs, not on words within a line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the effect of different alignment on the same line of text using a paragraph style with a single custom tab stop, right aligned against the right margin.

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

$section_style = $section->getStyle();
$position =
    $section_style->getPageSizeW()
    - $section_style->getMarginRight()
    - $section_style->getMarginLeft();
$phpWord->addParagraphStyle(
    'leftRight',
    ['tabs' => [new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Tab('right', $position)]]);

$section->addText('Left Text\tRight Text', [], 'leftRight');
```

Comment: 8500 seems very magical so I decided to calculate it like this:
`$section_style = $section->getStyle(); $position = $section_style->getPageSizeW() - $section_style->getMarginRight() - $section_style->getMarginLeft();`
This way the right text appears exactly at the right margin of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You should to do this, just define style by apart and send as parameter in addTextRun.

```
   $phpWord->addParagraphStyle('pStyler', array('align' => 'right'));

   $textrun = $section->addTextRun('pStyler');

   $textrun->addText(htmlspecialchars("Some text here..."));
```